# How to solve the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^n}{e^n}$.

Tags: limits

Please help me to evaluate this limit.
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^n}{e^n}$$ I am totally confused about this. I tried with $L'Hospital$ but failed.

Comment: $n^n=e^{n\ln n}$, $\frac{n^n}{e^{n}} = e^{n\ln n-n}$

Comment: Can you show us your attempt, please, in your post, please?

Answer (score 3):

$\frac{n^n}{e^n}=(\frac{n}{e})^n$ and for $n\geq3$ the base is greater than $1$. Conclusion?

Comment: It can easily be seen that it is $(+\infty)^{+\infty}$, the limit is quite clearly infinite.

Answer (score 2):

This diverges
pretty violently
and can be shown to do so
in many ways.

Here is one of them:

If
$n > 2e$ then
$\dfrac{(n)^n}{e^n}
\gt \dfrac{(2e)^n}{e^n}
=2^n
\to \infty
$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim _{ n\rightarrow \infty  }{ \frac { n^ n }{ e^ n }  } =\lim _{ n\rightarrow \infty  }{ (\frac{n}{e})^n } $$

Apply exponent rule: $a^n=e^{\ln(a^n)}=e^{n.\ln(a)}$

In this case we get: $$(\frac{n}{e})^n=e^{n\ln(\frac{n}{e})}$$

$$=\lim _{ n\rightarrow \infty  }(e^{n\ln(\frac{n}{e})})$$

Apply the Limit Chain Rule: if $\lim _{ u\rightarrow b  }f(u)=L,$ and $\lim _{ x\rightarrow a  }g(x)=b,$ and $f(x)$ is continuous at $x=b$. Then: $\lim _{ x\rightarrow a  }f(g(x))=L$

In this problem, $g(n)=n\ln(\frac{n}{e}),f(u)=e^u$

$$\lim _{ n\rightarrow \infty  }(n\ln(\frac{n}{e}))=\infty$$
After simplifying, 
$$\lim _{ n\rightarrow \infty  }(e^n)=\infty$$